# How to update an image in a Java GUI

Tags: java, image, swing, user-interface

I have a GUI with several buttons and I'm using NetBeans GUI Builder to do. 
At the click of one of these I would like for it to open another frame containing a picture.

So I associate a listener (actionPerformed) the button and when clicked it opens actually post the new frame.

In the new frame I waxed a JLabel and then I associate the image of the label. I saw that to do that NetBeans generates this code:

```
label.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/img/tree.png")));
```

My problem is that the picture is overwritten several times during the execution of the program is not changed yet in the frame. 
That is, in the new frame is always displayed an old version of the image.

How can I do so that the image is always up to date? 
Thank you very much

---

The Code:

```
package View;

import Controller.Util;
import javax.swing.Icon;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class AlberoIpotesi extends javax.swing.JFrame {

   /** Creates new form AlberoIpotesi */
   public AlberoIpotesi() {
      initComponents();

      remove(label);
      revalidate(); 
      repaint();
      Decifra.sessioneDec.toString(".../src/img/tree");
      revalidate(); 
      repaint();
   }

   /** This method is called from within the constructor to
    * initialize the form.
    * WARNING: Do NOT modify this code. The content of this method is
    * always regenerated by the Form Editor.
    */
   @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
   // <editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc="Generated Code">                          
   private void initComponents() {

      jLabel1 = new javax.swing.JLabel();
      scroll = new javax.swing.JScrollPane();
      label = new javax.swing.JLabel();

      setDefaultCloseOperation(javax.swing.WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
      setTitle("Albero delle ipotesi");

      jLabel1.setFont(new java.awt.Font("Tahoma", 1, 14)); // NOI18N
      jLabel1.setText("Albero delle ipotesi");

      label.setHorizontalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.CENTER);
      label.setIcon(new javax.swing.ImageIcon(getClass().getResource("/Img/tree.png"))); // NOI18N
      label.setVerticalAlignment(javax.swing.SwingConstants.TOP);
      scroll.setViewportView(label);

      javax.swing.GroupLayout layout = new javax.swing.GroupLayout(getContentPane());
      getContentPane().setLayout(layout);
      layout.setHorizontalGroup(
         layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
         .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addGap(29, 29, 29)
            .addGroup(layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
               .addComponent(scroll, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 342, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
               .addComponent(jLabel1))
            .addContainerGap(29, Short.MAX_VALUE))
      );
      layout.setVerticalGroup(
         layout.createParallelGroup(javax.swing.GroupLayout.Alignment.LEADING)
         .addGroup(layout.createSequentialGroup()
            .addContainerGap()
            .addComponent(jLabel1)
            .addPreferredGap(javax.swing.LayoutStyle.ComponentPlacement.UNRELATED)
            .addComponent(scroll, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE, 374, javax.swing.GroupLayout.PREFERRED_SIZE)
            .addContainerGap(25, Short.MAX_VALUE))
      );

      pack();
   }// </editor-fold>                        

   /**
    * @param args the command line arguments
    */
   public static void start() {
      /* Set the Nimbus look and feel */
        //<editor-fold defaultstate="collapsed" desc=" Look and feel setting code (optional) ">
        /* If Nimbus (introduced in Java SE 6) is not available, stay with the default look and feel.
       * For details see http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/lookandfeel/plaf.html 
       */
      try {
         for (javax.swing.UIManager.LookAndFeelInfo info : javax.swing.UIManager.getInstalledLookAndFeels()) {
            if ("Nimbus".equals(info.getName())) {
               javax.swing.UIManager.setLookAndFeel(info.getClassName());
               break;
            }
         }
      } catch (ClassNotFoundException ex) {
         java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AlberoIpotesi.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      } catch (InstantiationException ex) {
         java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AlberoIpotesi.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      } catch (IllegalAccessException ex) {
         java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AlberoIpotesi.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      } catch (javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
         java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger(AlberoIpotesi.class.getName()).log(java.util.logging.Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
      }
        //</editor-fold>

      /* Create and display the form */
      java.awt.EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
         public void run() {
            new AlberoIpotesi().setVisible(true);
         }
      });
   }

   // Variables declaration - do not modify                     
   private javax.swing.JLabel jLabel1;
   public static javax.swing.JLabel label;
   public static javax.swing.JScrollPane scroll;
   // End of variables declaration                   
}
```

Comment: try the functions revalidate(); and repaint();

Comment: @schlagi123 Thanks for the reply but it does not work, the image always is not updated...

Comment: Can you add the code of your aforementioned frame?

Comment: @RichardKennethNiescior I edited the main message.

Answer (score 2):

I'd seperate the creation of the icon and the setIcon on the JLabel, like so:

```
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon("path/to/picture.png");
label.setIcon(icon);
```

That way you can change the icon's image later and update the label

```
icon = new ImageIcon("path/to/new_picture.png"); // Changes the icon
label.setIcon(icon); // Updates the label's icon
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but I need something different. I have one image (same name and same path) that is updated, not two different images.

Answer (score 0):

So basically what I understand is that you have a button which creates a new instance object of the frame you wish to display right? Then you have an image stored in a particular location of your project where you will recall the object to display the updated image as you say?

I am unaware of how you choose to launch your frame. But what I can suggest is that you make use of a parametrized constructor to change your image each time(if required) the frame is called.

https://www.dropbox.com/s/mpqvy9hgsvsgq9t/PeanutsAndPretzels.zip

I am not sure of the terms and conditions of stackoverflow and external project files. But I compiled something which may or may not help you. Give it a bash to get an idea perhaps.

Comment: I ran your project and it is not what I need. You have two static images that are never modified. 
I have an image that is created every time I click on the button (it always has the same name and same path). 

Basically I have a generic tree on which I perform the operations (add, remove, etc..). 
When I click on the button I call a method that generates the image of the tree (using Graphviz). 
So I have one image that changes over the time...